# What does pseudo-differential mean?

Tags: adc, voltage-measurement, differential

I often read the term pseudo-differential when looking for ADCs. I know common differential means that the ADC measures a difference between two of its pins (AN+, AN-). But what is the difference to pseudo-differential?

Comment: Basically a way to do differential (i.e. two input measurements) sampling using only one internal sampling circuit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pseudo-Differential means that the AN+ and AN- are not being sampled simultaneously. Therefore dynamic common mode rejection is not improved, but DC common mode rejection is. Also, the different sampling times will affect the apparent phase relationship between AN+ and AN-. For these reasons, Pseudo-Differential is only useful for DC signals.

To give you an example, it can be implemented like this:

[image]

The main thing to note is that there is a common sampling circuit. Sometimes two samples will be taken (one from each input), or chopping may be employed.

For more information take a look at this [Maxim app note](http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/1108).

Comment: So AN+ gets measured (relatively to GND) then AN- and then the difference is calculated and stored?

Comment: Yes, but not so much "measured" as sampled onto a cap as in the diagram. The resulting cap voltage is measured.